# How to use functon in ng-show?

Tags: angularjs

I need to use the custom function in ng-show as:

```
ng-show="funct(1.1) > funct(2.2)"

$scope.funct(value){
  value.value.replace(".", "");
}
```

Comment: You need to `return` something from the function, and it will probably get you a [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) error sooner or later

Comment: The compare logic is better placed in a controller where it can be tested properly. The parsing of a complex [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) is not as efficient as using a JavaScript expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the JavaScript [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function in case the value is passed as a string (but maybe it's not even necessary if your the only one who is going to use the function) and return the value.

See below **snippet**.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.funct = function(value) {
      return parseFloat(value);
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <span ng-show="funct(1.1) > funct(2.2)">
1.1 is > 2.2
</span>

<br />

  <span ng-show="funct(1.1) < funct(2.2)">
1.1 is not > 2.2
</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$scope.newFunction = function(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(".", "");
 };

<span ng-show="newFunction(3.1) > newFunction(2.2)">Yes, More</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ng-show="funct(1.1) > funct(2.2)"

$scope.funct(value){
 return value.toString().replace(".", "");
}
```

return a value from your function

Comment: I don't think `value.value` is correct, when you can see that the OP pass a simple decimal to the function

Comment: 'value'  attribute is undefined

Comment: didn't  see that incorrect logic for replace. also, you are passing integer value and it doesn't support `replace`. Probably use `value.toString().replace(".","")`